# Jquery uncaught syntax error. Works on test file, but not in production. Dropdown bootstrap 4 theme selector

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

```js
$("#themeDropdown").click(function(e) {
  themes = {
    'Cerulean': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Cosmo': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Cyborg': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Darkly': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Flatly': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Journal': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/journal/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Litera': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/litera/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Lumen': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Lux': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Materia': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/materia/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Minty': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Pulse': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/pulse/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Sandstone': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Simplex': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Sketchy': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Slate': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/slate/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Solar': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/solar/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Spacelab': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Superhero': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/superhero/bootstrap.min.css',
    'United': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/united/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Yeti': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/yeti/bootstrap.min.css',
  }
  var choice = $("#themeDropdown")
  choice.text(this.innerHTML);
  if (choice[0].innerHTML in themes) {
    $('#bootswatch').attr('href', themes[choice[0].innerHTML])
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootswatch" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"></li>
    <a aria:expanded="false" aria:haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#" id="themeDropdown">Themes</a>
    <div aria:labelledby="themeDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cerulean</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cosmo</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Cyborg</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Darkly</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Flatly</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Journal</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Litera</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lumen</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Lux</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Materia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Minty</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Pulse</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sandstone</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Simplex</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sketchy</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Slate</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Solar</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Spacelab</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Superhero</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">United</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Yeti</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">hapsida</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <div class="jumbotron container context" style="padding-bottom:3; padding-top:40">
    <h1 class="bg-secondary" id="somethingelse">some thing else</h1>
    <div class="container" style="max-height: 70%; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 20">
      <p>some other content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

I am trying to build a simple bootswatch theme selector using a dropdown menu. When I test the code as it stands, it works just as expected without any errors, but when I put it together with the rest of my code, it is throwing this error.

```
jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:1580 Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
    at Function.Sizzle.error (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:1580)
    at Sizzle.tokenize (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2232)
    at Sizzle.select (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2659)
    at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:884)
    at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2922)
    at new jQuery.fn.init (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:3032)
    at jQuery (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:98)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (ascii.html:83)
    at HTMLDocument.dispatch (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:5206)
    at HTMLDocument.elemData.handle (jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:5014)
Sizzle.error @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:1580
Sizzle.tokenize @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2232
Sizzle.select @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2659
Sizzle @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:884
find @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:2922
jQuery.fn.init @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:3032
jQuery @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:98
(anonymous) @ ascii.html:83
dispatch @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:5206
elemData.handle @ jquery-3.2.1.slim.js:5014
```

I have made sure that jquery is being loaded properly, and I also tried debugging by removing various elements, and it appears that the error is being thrown by the dropdown menu itself. I really have no idea what is causing this, but would really appreciate some guidance. I tried figuring out what is causing this error, but the reference to jquery is really vague. For the sake of further debugging, i stripped out all elements, but the error is still persisting.

My navbar does have another dropdown, so using a `navbar` or `a` or any other dropdown related class selectors wouldn't work.

I am testing on the latest Chrome and Firefox

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rqcxjc6h/4/)

For sake of completeness, here is my test JSFiddle that works:

[Test JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/securisec/vt4xzj5w/)

Comment: instead of using href-"#" use href="javascript:void(0)".. with jquery v3 and later and bootstrap3, "#"  not valid and throws similar error

Comment: @NagaSaiA Great suggestion! That makes the error dissapear, but the code does not work in changing the themes. It is interesting that i am using the same js/css files in the test file, but no error and it works

Comment: what is the new error in console?

Comment: There is no new error @NagaSaiA. It just doesnt do anything. I made the same change you suggested to the test file, and that stops working as expected also.

Comment: I dont think thats it. As I mentioned, the test file is working fine. I moved all the script sources to the head to test your theory, and it still works. The innerHTML is being used as the key to find the value in the themes object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my issue. My issue was that I was loading the script before the dom could finish populating.

Comment: Will do in about 21 hours when I am allowed to

Answer (score 0):

I did some jQuery rework.  I changed the selector, changed all the elements to use `javascript:void(0)`.

```js
$(".navbar a").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  themes = {
    'Cerulean': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cerulean/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Cosmo': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cosmo/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Cyborg': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/cyborg/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Darkly': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/darkly/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Flatly': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/flatly/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Journal': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/journal/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Litera': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/litera/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Lumen': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/lumen/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Lux': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Materia': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/materia/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Minty': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/minty/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Pulse': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/pulse/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Sandstone': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/sandstone/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Simplex': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/simplex/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Sketchy': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/sketchy/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Slate': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/slate/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Solar': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/solar/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Spacelab': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/spacelab/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Superhero': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/superhero/bootstrap.min.css',
    'United': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/united/bootstrap.min.css',
    'Yeti': 'https://bootswatch.com/4/yeti/bootstrap.min.css',
  }
  var choice = $(this).text();
  if (choice in themes) {
    $('#bootswatch').attr('href', themes[choice])
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://bootswatch.com/4/lux/bootstrap.min.css" id="bootswatch" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.6/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet">

<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-primary sticky-top">
  <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto mt-2 mt-lg-0">
    <li class="nav-item dropdown"></li>
    <a aria:expanded="false" aria:haspopup="true" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="javascript:void(0)" id="themeDropdown">Themes</a>
    <div aria:labelledby="themeDropdown" class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Cerulean</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Cosmo</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Cyborg</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Darkly</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Flatly</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Journal</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Litera</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Lumen</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Lux</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Materia</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Minty</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Pulse</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Sandstone</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Simplex</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Sketchy</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Slate</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Solar</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Spacelab</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Superhero</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">United</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="javascript:void(0)">Yeti</a>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="javascript:void(0)">hapsida</a>
    </div>
  </ul>
  <div class="jumbotron container context" style="padding-bottom:3; padding-top:40">
    <h1 class="bg-secondary" id="somethingelse">some thing else</h1>
    <div class="container" style="max-height: 70%; overflow: auto; margin-bottom: 20">
      <p>some other content</p>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks! Although this works, like my test code, In the production code, I am failing to make it work. The error does go away with `javascript:void(0)`, but i put a breakpoint on the functions entry, and when i click on an element, i never reach it. This could very well be because my prod navbar has another dropdown with a tags

Comment: Sure! I have a sample here https://pastebin.com/1b0HPWg8. This is the full version of everything that is going on with my generated HTML (it is being generated by a py script, but i have been making changes by SO manually on the generated HTML)